# SQL Select with Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

With this data

```
Team Name Won
X    Andy  1
X    Cara  1
X    Cara  1
X    Eric  0
X    Eric  0
X    Eric  0
X    Eric  0
Y    Bill  0
Y    Dave  0
Y    Dave  1
Y    Dave  1
```

I want for each team the number of players and the number of winners

```
Team Players Winners
X       3       2
Y       2       1
```

Does it in two queries:

```
select team, count(distinct Name) as Players from test group by team
select team, count(distinct Name) as Winners from test where Won=1 group by team
```

but I can't work out the syntax to do it in one. TIA for your help. John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation using `case`:

```
select team,
    count(distinct name) as Players,
    count(distinct case when won = 1 then name end) as winners
from test
group by team
```

Comment: Excellent. I managed to come up with an answer using four linked CTEs: this gives the same result set and is MUCH simpler.

I had no idea a case statement could be written without an else!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select team, count(distinct Name) as Players, sum(won) Winners 
from (select distinct * from test) tst 
group by team
```

You can test it here: http://rextester.com/QATLK24197

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by group by

select team,count(name) as players ,sum(won) winners from (
select team, Name,sum(distinct won) as won from test group by team,name
) group by team